# php/sql AND statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have my code:

```
$db_date2;
$today2 = date("Y-m-d");
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM todays_spend WHERE id =$user_id_session AND date=$today2";
        $date_records = mysql_query($sql1); 
        while($today_trip=mysql_fetch_assoc($date_records)){
        $db_date2 = $today_trip['date'];    
        }
        echo $db_date2;
```

It is saying  "Undefined variable: db_date2".  When I remove the AND statement it works. Am I doing the AND statement wrong? the 'date' field in my database is also saved in the format Y-m-d.

also tried the single qoutes '' around the variables, still not working!

Comment: $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM todays_spend WHERE id ='".$user_id_session."' AND date='".$today2."'";

Comment: Am I the only person who HATES concatenating strings to form a query?

Comment: The MySQL extension is deprecated in PHP5, and no longer exists in the latest versions; switch to using MySQLi or PDO, and then you can use prepared statements and bind variables instead

Comment: @WheatBeak. Probably not. But you are the only person I've met that brings attention to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write single quote`''` around your variable.

Write your query as below:-

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM todays_spend WHERE id ='$user_id_session' AND date='$today2'";
```

**Warning**

> mysql_* was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Hope it will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is using your variables as string in the query rather than their values so Just replace your code with the following:

```
$db_date2;
$today2 = date("Y-m-d");
        $sql1 =     
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM todays_spend WHERE id ='".$user_id_session."' AND date='".$today2."'";
        $date_records = mysql_query($sql1); 
        while($today_trip=mysql_fetch_assoc($date_records)){
        $db_date2 = $today_trip['date'];    
        }
        echo $db_date2;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your variables, you'll need single quotes:

This:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM todays_spend WHERE id =$user_id_session AND date=$today2";
```

Should be:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM todays_spend WHERE id ='$user_id_session' AND date='$today2'";
```